# C++ CLR Windows Forms undeclared Identifier

Tags: windows, c++-cli

I am getting this error and can not for the life of me figure out why.

Here is my universal.h

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "MainForm.h"
#include "ReportsForm.h"
#include "EditSTIGForm.h"
```

Here is my Main.cpp

```
#include "MainForm.h"
#include "Universal.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    STIGTR::MainForm MainForm;
    STIGTR::Form EditSTIGForm;
    STIGTR::Form ReportsForm;
    Application::Run(%MainForm);
}
```

And then my MainForm.h

```
private: System::Void STIGReportToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^            sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    ReportsForm ^ReportForm = gcnew ReportsForm;
    ReportForm->ShowDialog();
}
private: System::Void editSTIGToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    EditSTIGForm ^STIGForm = gcnew EditSTIGForm;
}
```

`ReportsForm` works just fine. But after adding in the other `EditSTIGForm` I get these errors:

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'EditSTIGForm' : undeclared identifier 160 1   STIGTR
Error   2   error C2065: 'STIGForm' : undeclared identifier 160 1   STIGTR
Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'EditSTIGForm' 160   1   STIGTR
```

Comment: If you're going to inline the implementations in the header file, you'll have to include `EditSTIGForm.h` in `MainForm.h` too.

Comment: I've included `Universal.H` in the `Main.h` which has the 'EditSTIGForm.h` included.

Comment: `Universal.h` includes `MainForm.h` before `EditSTIGForm.h`, but `EditSTIGForm` is needed by `MainForm.h` - you'll have to reorder your includes. But it would be easier to manage if you defined the implementations in the cpp files, this way you could simply forward-declare the used classes where needed.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I knew how to make that as answer